# Display post X of Y in category

Tags: posts, categories

I am trying to display a post number (**X**) on each single.php, based on what number that post is in it's category, followed by the total number of posts (**Y**) in the category.
So if there is 10 posts in my category "photos", the latest post should be "1/10".

**I found this solution for Y:**

```
<?php
$category = get_the_category(); 
echo $category[0]->category_count;
?>
```

**This solution almost does what I want for X**, but it is not based on category, and includes all posts:
http://wordpress.org/support/topic/show-post-number#post-1294235

Can anyone help? :-)

Comment: How do you want to order the posts? _Published_ date? _Modified_ date? ID? Alphabetical?

Comment: @t f by published date :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, this should do, what you want:

```
// Fetch all posts in the current post's (main) category
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'cat' => array_shift(get_the_category())->cat_ID,
);
$query = new WP_Query($args);

// The index of the current post in its (main) category
$X = 1;
$id = get_the_ID();
foreach ($query->posts as $cat_post)
    if ($id != $cat_post->ID)
        $X++;
    else
        break;

// The number of posts in the current post's (main) category
$Y = $query->found_posts;

// Now, display what we got...
echo $X.'/'.$Y;
```

What is happening?
We fetch **all** posts of the current (main) category, ordered by *Published* date. That way, we already have the total number of posts in that category. Then we iterate through the posts and increment a counter variable to track the index of the current post. Finally, we display these numbers somewhere.

Comment: @t f - you just saved my night! Thank you SO MUCH! Happy new year :-)